# Performance difference when using DATEADD and CAST in different order

Tags: sql-server, casting, query-performance, dateadd

I was shown a query by a co-worker where he was experiencing some dramatic performance issues while using DATEADD and CAST together. By switching the order he got much better performance. Why does the order matter so much performance wise?

This where clause runs well:

```
WHERE IHist.[DateTime] BETWEEN DATEADD(DD, -30,CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS Date)) AND DATEADD(DD, 1, CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS Date))
```

This where clause takes forever:

```
WHERE IHist.[DateTime] BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(DD, -30,GETUTCDATE()) AS DATE) AND CAST(DATEADD(DD, 1, GETUTCDATE()) AS DATE)
```

Comment: You can guess only. Please post execution plan :) I'd suspect it's index not being used when it runs slow. Perhaps SQL Server doesn't estimate well  and has to store data in tempdb...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the values are static, it is better to define them at the beginning

```
declare @d1 date, @d2 date
select
    @d1 = DATEADD(DD, -30, CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS Date)),
    @d2 = DATEADD(DD,   1, CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS Date))
```

And then use in WHERE clause

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. It was much more efficient this way. Thanks!